# Is it possible to get RSS in Omnet++ without using INET framework?

Tags: omnet++

I want to get RSS (received signal strength) in Omnet but, when I search it on the internet, almost everyone suggests solutions related to INET framework. Is there a way getting or calculating RSS without using any Omnet++ framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. OMNeT++ itself does not contain any radio model nor any model of communication system.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So, can we consider radio range as a RSS? For example if a node has high radio range, also can we say it has high RSS?

Comment: Radio range depends on various factors (e.g. frequency, transmit power, modulation etc.). Radio range cannot be directly mapped to RSS.

Comment: As suggested, OMNeT++ has nothing to do with radios, transmission ranges etc. That are things that handled at higher abstraction level (in various frameworks). This is somewhat similar to asking:

I want to make a sentence bold in my essay that I'm writing on my Windows machine, but all answers came up with how to do it in MS Office or Libre Office, but nothing comes up how to do it on Windows...